# VB.NET Do I need to close filestream at class finalize?

Tags: vb.net, class, filestream, streamreader

I have a class in which I have declared a FileStream and a StreamReader:

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

```
Friend Class clsFileReader

    Private _fs As IO.FileStream
    Private _sr As IO.StreamReader
```

I would like ask if I explicitely need to close these like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()

    _fs.Close()
    _sr.Close()

End Sub
```

... or if that is done automatically.

Thank you for the help!

ps: I can not use "using" because I want to read the file line by line like this:

```
Public Function ReadLine() As String
    Debug.Assert(Not _sr.EndOfStream)

    _sCurrentLineString = _sr.ReadLine

    _iCurentLineIndex = _iCurentLineIndex + 1

    Return _sCurrentLineString

End Function
```

Comment: Streams are IDisposable so wrap them in a using case. It is good practice to always close resources you use so you're sure they're closed and not relying on garbage collection to maybe close them. Basically - close them the moment your done with them (usually way before class finalizer)

Comment: I have to keep them open because I am reading the file line by line. Else I would not have to use this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the same fonctionality as found in the stream. Implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface and call .Dispose on your class instance when you're done with it. Same as you would do with a stream.

Here's a quick example.

```
Class clsFileReader : Implements IDisposable

   Private _fs As IO.FileStream
   Private _sr As IO.StreamReader

   ' Flag: Has Dispose already been called? 
   Dim disposed As Boolean = False 

   ' Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers. 
   Public Sub Dispose() _
              Implements IDisposable.Dispose
      Dispose(True)
      GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)           
   End Sub 

   ' Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
   Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
      If disposed Then Return 

      If disposing Then 
         ' Free any other managed objects here. 
         ' 
         _fs.Close()
         _sr.Close()
      End If 

      ' Free any unmanaged objects here. 
      '
      disposed = True 
   End Sub 

   Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
      Dispose(False)      
   End Sub 

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks really elaborated. I was hoping I could use some fool safe method and do that in the class. I was hoping I could avoid doing something like .Close (that was my first thought) or .Dispose from "outside". Is that possible?

Comment: @tmighty The problem with Finalize is that you never know when it will be called. It's even possible it'll only be called when the application closes. By calling Dispose yourself, you have the knowledge that the stream will be closed at that moment.